# Sql in sql server with convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to use convert in an where clause in the select statement. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10  [SurveyResult].*
                        ,[Ticket].[RefNumber] 
FROM [SurveyResult] 
LEFT JOIN [Ticket] ON [SurveyResult].[TicketID] = [Ticket].[TicketID] 
JOIN [SurveyResponse] AS SurveyResponse1 ON [SurveyResult].[ResultID] = SurveyResponse1.[ResultID] 
JOIN [QuestionAnswer] AS QuestionAnswer1 ON SurveyResponse1.[AnswerID] = QuestionAnswer1.[AnswerID] 
JOIN [SurveyQuestion] AS SurveyQuestion1 ON QuestionAnswer1.[QuestionID] = SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID]
WHERE SurveyQuestion1.[SurveyID] = [SurveyResult].[SurveyID]
    AND SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID] = 'C86CB39A-8FE0-4FE8-B38F-17F1BE611016'
    AND CONVERT(INT, SurveyResponse1.[Response]) >= 1
    AND CONVERT(INT, SurveyResponse1.[Response]) <= 5
```

The problem is that I get some errors when converting the values to integer in the where statement.

I know I have some rows that don't contain numbers in the Response column but I filter those so without the convert part in the where clause I get only numbers so it works like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ResponseID]
  ,[ResultID]
  ,[Response]
  FROM [WFSupport].[dbo].[SurveyResponse]
  JOIN QuestionAnswer ON SurveyResponse.AnswerID = QuestionAnswer.AnswerID 
 WHERE QuestionAnswer.QuestionID = 'C10BF42E-5D51-46BC-AD89-E57BA80EECFD'
```

And in the results I get numbers but once I add the convert part in the statement I I get an error that it can't convert some text to numbers.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: 2008, I was under the impression that sql server short circuits evaluation to this condition: QuestionAnswer.QuestionID = 'C10BF42E-5D51-46BC-AD89-E57BA80EECFD'  would filter the numbers before converting them but it doesn't work

Comment: Please check [Short-circuiting section of this article](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do like Mark says or just have NULL values default to something numerical, this would give you a where statement like:

```
WHERE SurveyQuestion1.[SurveyID] = [SurveyResult].[SurveyID]
    AND SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID] = 'C86CB39A-8FE0-4FE8-B38F-17F1BE611016'
    AND CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(SurveyResponse1.[Response],0)) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

The important part is the ISNULL() function and I also used BETWEEN to avoid duplicate converts.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
            [SurveyResult].*,
            [Ticket].[RefNumber]        
        FROM 
            [SurveyResult]
        LEFT JOIN [Ticket] ON [SurveyResult].[TicketID] = [Ticket].[TicketID]
        JOIN [SurveyResponse] AS SurveyResponse1
             ON [SurveyResult].[ResultID] = SurveyResponse1.[ResultID]
        JOIN [QuestionAnswer] AS QuestionAnswer1
             ON SurveyResponse1.[AnswerID] = QuestionAnswer1.[AnswerID]
        JOIN [SurveyQuestion] AS SurveyQuestion1
             ON QuestionAnswer1.[QuestionID] = SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID]
    where  SurveyQuestion1.[SurveyID] = [SurveyResult].[SurveyID]
      AND SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID] = 'C86CB39A-8FE0-4FE8-B38F-17F1BE611016'
      AND CASE SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID]
               WHEN 'C86CB39A-8FE0-4FE8-B38F-17F1BE611016'
               THEN Convert(int, SurveyResponse1.[Response])
               ELSE 0
          END BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

(The `AND SurveyQuestion1.[QuestionID] = 'C86CB39A-8FE0-4FE8-B38F-17F1BE611016'` is retained in case the query is using an index on QuestionID - if not, it can be removed, as the same condition is implicit in the subsequent `CASE` condition.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 sr.*, t.[RefNumber] 
FROM dbo.SurveyResult sr
JOIN dbo.SurveyResponse sr2 ON sr.[ResultID] = sr2.[ResultID] 
JOIN dbo.QuestionAnswer sa ON sr2.[AnswerID] = sa.[AnswerID] 
JOIN dbo.SurveyQuestion sq ON sa.[QuestionID] = sq.[QuestionID] AND sq.[SurveyID] = sr.[SurveyID]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Ticket t ON sr.[TicketID] = t.[TicketID] 
WHERE sq.[QuestionID] = 'C86CB39A-8FE0-4FE8-B38F-17F1BE611016'
    AND CAST(ISNULL(sr2.[Response], 0) AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```